# How do I ensure a REST API does not have a bottleneck when it receives requests?

Tags: ip, bandwidth, upload

I'm creating a REST API that will listen on a public URL and accept uploads of large amounts of data. I understand how to scale software processes using message queues, but what I don't understand is how to avoid a bottleneck between users and reaching my message queue server farm. To my understanding, at some point I have a machine listening to requests on an IP address, and that will be a single point of failure bottleneck. But this sounds really wrong since, you know, sites like google.com exist.

My subsequent question is if you can achieve this scalability for a fixed IP address instead of a fixed URL. Not because I have to do this, I just want to understand if in the practical sense of running a website (or other HTTP server) scalability can only be achieved by using a dynamic number of IPs.

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes much sense as written; there are no limits on throughput built into IP.

Comment: @MadHatter in this universe, not per the IP protocol specification.

Comment: This universe or otherwise, the question still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MadHatter asked question from a different vantage point that hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: @ceejayoz see rewrite.

Comment: "To my understanding, at some point I have a machine listening to requests on an IP address, and that will be a single point of failure bottleneck. But this sounds really wrong since, you know, sites like google.com exist." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocast etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, that answers my question. If you post as answer (with a sentence of explanation) I'll accept.

Comment: @ceejayoz in other words: I got downvotes, and completely rewrote my question, as you're supposed to do. You were able to easily answer my new question from here. Still downvotes though. Is there anything else I should be doing I'm not aware of?

Comment: Well, even rewritten, it's not really on-topic here.

Comment: @ceejayoz covered under "Network routing, switches, and firewalls".

Comment: It's also essentially a request for learning materials, which is one of the close reasons.

Comment: @ceejayoz at no point did I request learning materials, and I do not even see your basis for that.

Answer (score 2):

> What physical bottleneck determines how much data can be uploaded to one IP address?

The hop with the least bandwidth available for your traffic.

---

Updated question, IP Endpoint redundancy: See [HSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol) or [CARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol). See also [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29)

For multi-site redundnacy see: [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) or [Geocast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocast), both of which are quite expensive and complicated.

Comment: Flipped the question around which hopefully clarifies it.

Comment: Updated my answer